# async task queue doesn't work (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I try to execute 2 task in the backgroup in sequence with following code:

```
var group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
            println("start task 1");
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(10000);
            });
dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
            println("start task 2");
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(10000);
        });


dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

When running Task 1 and Task 2 are executed at the same time, not inqequence.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the global queue **CONCURRENT** queue,if you want task execute in order,create serial queue

```
 let serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.helloHwc",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
dispatch_group_async(group,serialQueue, {
    println("start task 1");
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(10);
});
dispatch_group_async(group,serialQueue, {
    println("start task 2");
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(10);
});


dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

**Update with document**

> Blocks submitted to a serial queue are executed one at a time in FIFO order. Note, however, that blocks submitted to independent queues may be executed concurrently with respect to each other. Blocks submitted to a concurrent queue are dequeued in FIFO order but may run concurrently if resources are available to do so